# Display hours in 2 digit format

Tags: sql, sybase

I am adding hours to the datetime object in sybase.

```
    dateadd(hh,4,date_val)
```

The problem is that if the current hour is 2am, after adding 4 hours it is displaying 6 instead of 06. How do i achieve the appending of 0 if the time is in single digit? Please help.

Comment: try using case `select case when len(cast(dateadd(hh,4,date_val)) as varchar)=1 then '0'+cast(dateadd(hh,4,date_val)) as varchar) End`

Comment: seems to be some error in brackets.

Comment: `select case when len(cast(dateadd(hh,4,date_val)) as varchar)=1 then '0'+cast(dateadd(hh,4,date_val) as varchar) End` see if this works?

Comment: Do you care about the rest of the date or just the hour portion?

Comment: just the hour and minute portion.